# React Native duplicate symbol on XCode when installing react-native-adapter

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am having the error below when I installed the react-native-adapter via npm.

Can someone please show me how to fix this issue?

Error:

```
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy' in
Release-iphoneos/EXPermissions/libEXPermissions.a(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)
Release-iphoneos/UMReactNativeAdapter/
```